# Endless redirect loop in Facebook canvas application

Tags: facebook

I have tried to search this, but have found no answers. I have [had] a working application on Facebook up until yesterday, then all hell broke loose and it simply doesn't come up. Please keep in mind, nothing changed on my end. The application has been running for over a year with no problems.

Yesterday, I accessed the application like normal and got an additional permission request for access to my friends list. Strange, again because I have made no changes to the code or the configuration on FB. I accepted the request and now instead of the application coming up, it simply goes into an endless oauth login redirect loop. In fact it doesn't even look like it ever calls my application url as I cannot debug it (it never breaks on the code)

I guess my question is, does anyone know of something changing recently on FB to cause this?

The application can be found at: https://apps.facebook.com/myworkoutlog

And as I wrote this, the app came up, but after closing the browser and starting again, back into the endless loop. Any help would be great. If you need additional information, please just ask.

**Edit:**
I finally got it into debug and it breaks when I try to get an access_token using a verification code: (OAuthException - #100) Invalid verification code format.

Comment: You solved it ? I too getting same short of problem only in IE. Can you help me for this ? i'm using JS SDK

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me ;)

include_once "facebook.php";

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'     => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret'    => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'cookie' => true
    ));

$fb_user = $facebook->getUser();
if($fb_user){
    if(isset($_GET['code']) && isset($fb_user)){
            $fbAppNs = 'appOnFacebookNameSpace';
            $facebookAppUrl = 'https://apps.facebook.com/'.$fbAppNs;
            header("Location: " . $facebookAppUrl);
            exit;
    }
    try{
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        $smarty->assign('name', $user_profile['first_name'].' '.$user_profile['last_name']);
        $smarty->assign('email', $user_profile['email']);
    }catch(FacebookApiException $e){
        error_log($e);
        $user = NULL;
    }
}else{
    $loginData = array(
        'scope'     => 'email,publish_stream',
        'canvas'    => 1,
        'fbconnect' => 0,
        'redirect_uri' => $siteConfigs['WEBSITE_URL'].'fblead/'
        );
   $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($loginData);
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href = '$loginUrl';</script>";
   exit;
}
```